# External CSS and JS files in MVC model

Tags: php, html, css, templates

So, I'm trying to build a web site based on my own MVC-like PHP model.

let's say that every view consists of at least 2 parts:

let those be 'template.php' and 'mypage.php' (the second part depends on the specific page, the first part is common).

**template.php** has the following code (in simplified version):

```
<html>
<title>Sometitle</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/gen.css' type='text/css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/gen.js'></script>
<?php echo $other_external_files; ?>
</head>
<body>
<div class="some_header_and other stuff">...</div>
<div class="workfield">
<?php include_once mypage.php; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem that 'mypage.php' (as well as some other pages) has some specific .css and .js files that should be included.

**The question is**: Which is the best option to include these files (how and where)?

**Here are my thoughts:**

1. I could define the variable `$other_external_files` in a model or controller, but don't really want to do that, because .css file is normally part of the view and I could hardcode it in 'mypage.php', if only it would not need to stay in `<head>`.
2. I understand that .css and .js files can be dynamically included with JavaScript, but I'd like to avoid this solution if there's no strong need in it.
3. I could define all these variables in the corresponding models. The problem here is, that from the very beginning I've been trying to structure my models based on the content (thus, I have universal models (files and Classes) like 'Users', 'Shop_items' etc, that don't necessarily correspond to every view file (it means I basically don't have any mypage_model.php, just 'items_model', 'users_model' etc.). Defining title of the page in a model will force me to add lots of model files.
4. I could possibly auto-define the variable `$other_external_files` in  the core View class, like this:

-

```
function __construct($action){
$this->action = $action.'.php';
$this->css_file = 'css/'.$action.'.css';
}

function generate($view_lvl, $data = null){
$other_external_files = $this->css_file;
require_once $action;
}
```

However, this approach seems to be limited, because possibly there can be a situation, when I'd like to include several files with quite different names.

**My personal choose for now is the 3rd.,** because it allows not only to append css and js, but also easily define title of the document and other possible variables... but before multiplying my files, I'd like to consult experienced programmers you are if it's really the right way.

Thanks a lot and sorry for a long question. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: I would store files to be included on a per page bases in the db and include them depending on which page you're on. ie have css include js includes ect... and loop through files needing be included and do so for each page. this way each page can have different/multiple js or css includes on a per page basis.

Comment: So, you suggest to store something like pairs **page_id=>corresponding_external_files in db**? Well, way to go.. But if I had inline css/js, then I could simply write it down in the view.html file... and in your case I'm starting to rely on DB for such a basic task.

Comment: Oh, and every time I have to start a new .css file I should add it to the DB with the corresponding path and id? Seems kinda annoying. Or is it a common practice? Your approach also means that **I'll have to connect to db and make a query even on totally static html pages**, like error pages with external .css?

Comment: you could have your common css and js files static in your template and just have the extras in the db. If you don't like the idea don't do it, just a suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually don't go for this kind of formation. Experience has proven to me that if I separate each view/page as a single file, it'll be more useful. I always use your strategy for pages that they're more template like and when it comes to page's distinct properties like title I make it so strict to not get confused. For instance, I get those properties from a single place like a database table of `pages`.

For resources like JavaScript or CSS files I include them exactly like in a normal page in every view. I think it's better to not populate them in a variable like `$other_external_files;` and instead put them differently in each separated view.

For example, this is my `about.php` view:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>About</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo ABS_PATH; ?>/css/extra.css' type='text/css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo ABS_PATH; ?>/css/extra2.css' type='text/css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo ABS_PATH; ?>/js/extra.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my `contact.php` view:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo ABS_PATH; ?>/css/extra3.css' type='text/css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo ABS_PATH; ?>/js/extra.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo ABS_PATH; ?>/js/extra2.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

For my very dynamic page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $TITLE; ?></title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo ABS_PATH; ?>/css/extra3.css' type='text/css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo ABS_PATH; ?>/js/extra.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo ABS_PATH; ?>/js/extra2.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

If you look at my dynamic page you see that I pass actual data to it. This means I get relevant data from my controller and then I pass it through.